# java script image changing and fading

Tags: javascript

hi have problem in image fading and image changing..like slide show...i have tried image slide show it as come out well but when i tired to some effect...i.e before the image changes ..it has fade and then next image has to come in fade effect....then brighter so on....wht to any simple example or any small.or any url to go through ...it will help me out...thk u

Comment: It would help if you showed us some of the source code you already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty hard to get to the 'core' of your question; but here is a [small project](http://github.com/oyvindkinsey/JsSlideshow) I have.

You can check out a demo [here](http://kinsey.no/projects/jsslideshow/)